# How can I return a query result as JSON?

Tags: clojure, ring

In this example I have created a simple api which query's the database and fetches back all documents. I would like the response to be returned as a json object. However the actual output is:`{:text "some text", :title "title", :id "1"}{:text "some more text", :title "another title", :id "2"}` I'm very new to clojure so probably missing something obvious.

handler.clj

```
(ns app.handler
  (:use compojure.core)
  (:use cheshire.core)
  (:use app.document)
  (:require [compojure.handler :as handler]
            [ring.middleware.json :as middleware]
            [compojure.route :as route]))

(defroutes app-routes
           (context "/documents" [] (defroutes documents-routes)
                                    (GET  "/" [] (list-documents)))
           (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (-> (handler/api app-routes)
      (middleware/wrap-json-body)
      (middleware/wrap-json-response)))
```

storage.clj

```
 (ns app.storage
  (:import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource)
  (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :refer :all]))

  (def db
    {
      :classname   "org.sqlite.JDBC"
      :subprotocol "sqlite"
      :subname     "src/storage/sqlite.db"
    }
  )
```

document.clj

```
(ns app.document
  (:use app.storage)
  (:use ring.util.response)
  (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :refer :all]))

(defn list-documents []
  (let [results (query db ["select * from documents"])]
    (prn results)

    (cond (empty? results)
          (not_found ())
          :else
          (response (lazy-seq results)))))
```

Comment: Works for me. On the condition a response is a map, not a lazy-seq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Middleware that converts responses with a map or a vector for a body into a JSON response.

From the docstring of `wrap-json-response`. You're giving it a sequence, but it only accepts maps or vectors. Change `(response (lazy-seq results))` to `(response (vec results))`.

Edit: Changed my whole answer, I misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks! Is there no way to achieve this using ring.util.response ?

Comment: If you look at the [source](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-json/blob/master/src/ring/middleware/json.clj#L100) of `json-response` you can see that it's quite simple. It transforms the body from clojure datastructures to json and sets the appropriate headers. You could replicate that functionality quite easily, but I'd just add the dependency. At 125 lines of code for the whole library, it's not really a big deal.

Comment: So I tried the example you gave however I get this error: clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn

Comment: Oh, try to wrap it in `vec` to return a vector instead of a lazy-seq.

Comment: I've changed this answer, I didn't realize that you were already using `ring-json`.

Comment: Thanks! It returns json now. Out of interested what are you thoughts on using the clojure.java.jdbc query, would you recommend any better libraries?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158346/discussion-between-madstap-and-freid001).